# spark data frame assign unique number for companies

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset with fields company and contract number, I'd like to add another column called Company number used as a unique number for each company.

```
Company | contract number | Company number
amazon  | IO123456        | 1
google  | IO113456        | 2
google  | IO111456        | 2
yahoo   | IO111156        | 3
amazon  | IO111116        | 1
```

I tried using

```
window_spec = Window.partitionBy('Company')
Programmatic_df = Programmatic_df.withColumn('Company number', dense_rank().over(window_spec))
```

but it doesn't yield the result I wanted. It assigns index for each row per company instead of assigning an unique number for each company

```
Company | contract number | Company number
amazon  | IO123456        | 1
google  | IO113456        | 1
google  | IO111456        | 2
yahoo   | IO111156        | 1
amazon  | IO111116        | 2
```

What is the correct approach here?

Comment: How is it not working? Syntax error, wrong data, ...?

Comment: instead of giving unique number of each company it's giving index number to each record, I'll update my answer

Comment: I might add that this is probably a pretty bad idea. What happens if you add apple to your list?  It will become company number 2, everyone after that will suddenly get a different company number.

Comment: yes that's a valid point. in my case I only care about current month, doesn't matter what the other months are like though.

Comment: In that case, I think you want to order by company, not partition by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
window_spec = Window.partitionBy('Company')
```

To this:

```
window_spec = Window.orderBy('Company')
```

Because you are ordering by company and not partitioning by company